# NodeJS: Fail to use service account to access Gmail API

Tags: node.js, gmail-api, service-accounts

I have a G suite domain and open a service account with domain wide delegation. The service account also have owner identity in the project.
I enable gmail API and add the scope refer to (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation "Delegate domain-wide authority to your service account")
I enable less secure app setting too.

Here is my code:

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');

var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    "service@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    null,
    "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n....",
    ['https://mail.google.com/', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata'] // I have also tried https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.imap_admin
);

jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(tokens); // successful print the token
});
```

But when I use this token to try listing email:
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?access_token={access_token}

Error occurs.

```
{
    "error":{
        "errors":[
            {
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "failedPrecondition",
                "message": "Bad Request"
            }
        ],
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Bad Request"
    }
}
```

I don't want a workaround, I intend to solve the problem with service account. I success to use the Gmail API with other authentication options.
I have read many articles but none of them help. I have stuck with it for a week, any advice will be very appreciated.

I will be free to provide more detail in case it matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a sub claim should solve this problem.

```
var jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    "service@xxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    null,
    "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n....",
    ['https://mail.google.com/', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify', 
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata'], // I have also tried https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.imap_admin
    'user@yourdomain.com' // use a user email in your domain since service account do not have Gmail box
);
```

Comment: I tried it ...  bit it's failing ...  Ant additional trick ? ( my Service Account has domain-wide delegation of authority w thesess copes) Eexactly same parameters... ( excepted user account in the domain  being mine ) and I get :  Error: unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method. ... tnaks for feedback   :